# Spring Data Neo4j in combination with Spring-Social and Spring-Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-social, spring-data-neo4j

I am in an early stage of a small Spring-based project which utilizes Spring Data Neo4j with  an embedded database (but possibly could use a server instance in a later development , too). 
My data model and relationships have been designed, Spring Security (with Neo4j), MVC and tiles are set up and also seem to be fully functional. 
Now I have the additional requirement to allow login with social networks. 
I'm really stuck with trying to integrate Spring Social with my above mentioned setup. Basically I have a rough idea that I need to make use of the cross-store Neo4j component but have no real clue, how I could start with it.

I tried to find something useful for my case (SDN Neo4j + Spring Social Security) on github but was not really successful with that either.

Can anyone provide me an example configuration or even point me to some examples (I obviously didn't find before) ... any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a Spring Social connector yet, but it shouldn't be too hard to write (there is one for Mongo). If nothing else, you can use the https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ directly form a service, exposing the google oauth callback from a Spring Controller, should work too.

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j connection repository for Spring social has been implemented here using neo4j-ogm. You can reuse that. https://github.com/maciossek/spring-social-neo4j